# Is this an elliptic curve $x^2+y^2=k^2(1+x^2y^2)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

Is this an elliptic curve $x^2+y^2=k^2(1+x^2 y^2)$ over rationals? If yes, how can we transform it into usual form? My friend sent me this curve.

Comment: If I remember correctly, elliptic curves have degree $3$ which is not the case here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve

Comment: I think Edwards describes how to put the curve into Weierstrass form in his paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-03/S0273-0979-07-01153-6/S0273-0979-07-01153-6.pdf

Comment: Thanks all!....